# Customizing email background while composing new email

Tags: css, email, outlook

I'm using outlook 365, I have a task to compose an email while using different background. I manage to put the customized image as the background of the email. My problem that I'm facing right now is disable the background-repeat option (I'm seeing the same image multiple times), what I want to see only one instance of this image. 
What I tried so far:

1) Use a different theme and change the background, but I'm getting the same result

2) I tried to save this custom theme (I only added a different background and saved it as html file), then I edited it but after I attempted to reload the theme, outlook crashes (maybe because I did not put the resource).

Is there an option to see the html code of the theme without saving it locally? How can I upload other backgrounds to outlook 365 in order to change permanently the background of all the emails that I will be composing later on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The repeating background CSS is not supported. You’ll need to make sure your images are large enough to cover the area, rather than repeating the image. Check out this link here - point 3 has more info about backgrounds in Outlook. https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how-to-create-excellent-emails-for-outlook-com/#outlook_dot_com_tip3